# How to hide "[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop ..." in tests?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, testing

I have a VUE component which accepts a prop of type `Number`. I want to have a test (using vue test utils - jest) covering the situation where the prop is not a number and how it renders in such a case (lets say the value is an `A` character). The "issue" I am facing is the test runner prints `[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "count". Expected Number with value NaN, got String with value "A".`

I think I understand why this happens, but at the same time I want to have the test in place and don't want that string to print out.

**So I am looking for a way to dismiss or hide the warning when in test mode.** Is that doable? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can configure [`app.config.warnHandler`](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-config-warnhandler) via the [`global.config`](https://test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#global-config) mounting option to filter out that warning:

```js
const wrapper = mount(MyComponent, {
  props: {
    count: 'A', // should be a number
  },
  global: {
    config: {
      warnHandler(msg, instance, trace) {
        if (msg.includes('Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "count"')) {
          // ignore warning
          return
        }
        console.warn(msg, instance, trace)
      },
    }
  }
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-filter-out-warnings-in-tests?file=package.json,src%2Fcomponents%2F__tests__%2FMyComponent.spec.ts)

Comment: thanks a lot Tony, seems this does not work for me. The handler is not called at all. I have found this global object to be app level settings. Should it work for vue/test-utils?

Comment: ahh, I see where my issue comes from now: I am using vue v2. Tried to define localVue.config.warnHandler, but seems not working either. Thanks a lot for your time helping me!